# MySQL use view to access table under different name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a performance and best-practice question concerning mysql tables.
I´m working on an application which connects to a database which gets filled by other programms.
This system is deployed in differnet locations, and from location to location the name of some databases-tables can change (but the fields in this tables etc stay the same).

As I don´t want to change all sql querys in my application for every location, I thought about creating a mysql view which simply mirrors the contents of this table to the normaly used table-name.

Is this a suitable solution, or could it get awfully slow with big tables?

Comment: So you have one application with a database that connects to other databases looks in this table (which the name changes) and the results of all the tables?

Comment: Q1. Do the other programmers just import or update as well - is there an update field?

Comment: @Richard Housham, no, my applications shares the database with other applications and there are a few tables which are just read by my application. The other programms just write (but its not possible to change to which table they are writing).

Answer (score 1):

Simple views (created as `SELECT * FROM table`) behave like the specified table performance wise.

It should be a suitable solution for your case.

Comment: ok, that sounds good. there are no joins or else in the statement, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

mmm, this is tricky. If there are multiple tables then a quick and dirty version for this would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
Union
SELECT * FROM table2
Union
SELECT * FROM table3) t
```

Which I think will work. You will of course have problems with pagination, sorting and searching - because you will have to try and do this over 3 or more tables.

Another way would be this

Create a table with the table names and a counter

```
ImportTable
name
id
```

Now in this you can enter the names of the tables and the last id that you want to import from.

Create another table to import the records

```
TableRecords
source
id 
field1
field2
 etc
```

Now run something that goes through the tables in `ImportTable`  grabs any new records and shoves them into `TableRecords.

Now this becomes really simply you can query `TableRecords` and have pagination sorting and searching with no of the previous troubles.

Make something that runs this every 2 minutes say so `TableRecords` will be 2 mins behind but everything will be really easy and run like a dream.